# Dll not match with assembly

Tags: vb.net

When I add a .dll file as a reference in C# application it shows an error:

```
A reference to the "....dll" could not be added.
Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly
or COM component.
```

Comment: The 99.9% odds are that the message is accurate.  The DLL you select *must* be a managed assembly or a COM server that contains a type library.  You cannot add a reference to a regular DLL that contains unmanaged code.  That requires pinvoke.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your dll is not in the protected folder? For example you need some administrator rights for certain folders.. Try to move your dll into another folder and then try to add it and compile it